# Sphinxsearch Crash in Docker Container on Cloud Instance

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sphinx, piler

I have Piler mailarchive (http://www.mailpiler.org/) running in a docker container and locally it works well. Now I wanted to run Piler with Traefik in my cloud instance but I can't see why the Sphinx server crashed. I did not change anything in the Sphinx configuration.

The only thing that has changed is that a Traefik proxy runs on the cloud which routes to the containers. Sphinx only works locally?

searchd is managed via supervisor:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sphinx]
command=searchd indexer --all --config /usr/local/etc/piler/sphinx.conf
user=piler
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Error:

```
piler  | Sphinx 3.3.1 (commit b72d67b)
piler  | Copyright (c) 2001-2020, Andrew Aksyonoff
piler  | Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
piler  |
piler  | 2020-09-23 10:19:12,094 INFO success: sphinx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
piler  | 2020-09-23 10:19:12,097 INFO exited: sphinx (exit status 1; not expected)
piler  | 2020-09-23 10:19:13,106 INFO spawned: 'sphinx' with pid 353
piler  | [Wed Sep 23 10:19:13.115 2020] [353] FATAL: malformed or unknown option near 'indexer'; use '-h' or '--help' to see available options.
piler  | [Wed Sep 23 10:19:13.117 2020] [353] WARNING: Error saving searchd state
piler  | [Wed Sep 23 10:19:13.119 2020] [353] shutdown complete
```

Sphinx Version: 3.3.1
Opperating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Docker: 19.03
Docker-Compose:1.27.3
Piler: 1.3.9

Comment: Well `command=searchd indexer --all ...` looks wrong. YOu calling `searchd` comand with 'indexer' as a parameter. That doesnt work! `searchd` and `indexer` as *separate* binaries. The container will probably need to run BOTH `indexer` (to build indexes) and then run `searchd` (to serve them). If your conainer doesnt have a persistent volumn, will need to make sure indexer completes before starting searchd

Comment: @barryhunter Yes you are right!

command=searchd --config /usr/local/etc/piler/sphinx.conf --nodetach

That would be right.